# SQL performance Use DateTime or int for index

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, indexing, query-optimization

I have the following history table that I plan on implementing, but I'm wondering what would give the best performance. I will have a USP that gets all records from hID X on day N (it will always select all available records for a given day). The records will be grouped per 15 minutes and 'Value' will be the number of times hID did something.

Would it be faster to have a DateTime column with an index on it, or would it be better to split this off to an INT and save it as YYYYmmdd and a separate column for the time?
If I go for the last option I would have to convert it back to a DateTime in the backend, as the app needs a DateTime to display the data.

### Table A

- Id (PK int)
- hId (FK int) FK to a table with the full key (up to 300 characters long)
- Date (DateTime)
  -Value (int)
- Count (int)

Above table will get around 2.000.000 new records per day (for the current amount of users, so may increase later) and only keep records of 7 days max. After that, a USP will delete them.

### Table B (existing table)

- Id (int)
- Key (nvarchar 300)

Comment: What's the database?

Comment: "Would it be faster to..." -- it all depends on the specific query you want to optimize. Please add it to the question.

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Sorry, just added the correct tags.

Comment: Are you interested in a time? If not use `date` data type. Either way, a index on a `datetime` or `date` column will be fine, don't store your dates as integer, you lose so much functionality for no benefit.

Answer (score 1):

Sql Server has a built-in Date-only type. Given you will tend to always select all records for a given day, I suggest having both a `DateTime` column **and** a `Date` column (possibly as a computed column), where you can have an index on the `Date` column for your queries.

Comment: That's unecessary, an index on the Datetime column will be sufficient, you can cast a `datetime` as `date` - that's completely sargable.

Comment: @Stu Sargeable but perhaps [not a good idea](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/cast-to-date-is-sargable-but-is-it-a-good-idea)

Comment: @SMor thanks for that link some interesting points.

Comment: A funkier option would be to add an `int` column that identifies the 15-minute _bucket_ during the day and then create an index on `( EventDate, QuarterHour )`. That would handle both the `where` clause and `group by`. A _covering index_ might make sense to optimize the whole query at that point.

Answer (score 0):

From the perspective of index space, DATETIME values are kept in eight bytes, and INT in four so DATETIME indexes will be slightly bigger.  From the point of view of search algorithms, the developers of SQL Server have been working hard to optimize this for decades. Where clauses mentioning INT and DATETIME values are *very important* use cases for them. They spend entire careers making this stuff faster. It's not worthwhile to try to outsmart them. Just use the fruits of their labor.

My point: pick the data type *so your data closely models the real world.*  Don't distort your date-like data values  because you think INT might be faster than DATETIME. Use DATETIME, and take advantage of all the optimization in the software.

By the way, the correct way to do a WHERE search for a single day exploiting an index is this.

```
WHERE datetime_column >= '2021-04-15'
  AND datetime_column <  DATEADD(DAY, 1, '2021-04-15')
```

In other words you search for dates beginning at `>=` midnight on the day, and ending with anything earlier than `<` midnight on the next day. This does an efficient *range scan* on the index.

```
WHERE DATE(datetime_column) = '2021-04-15'    /!!! slower
```

does not.